# adding 2 numbers in assembly doesn't output the number but a random letter/symbol (need to convert result to ASCII ?)

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I'm adding 2 numbers in assembly, but when i write the output in a variable called result to the console it outputs a random letter or symbol, from researching it seems like i need to convert the number to ASCII and then output to console but I'm not sure how to do that, section of code below where calculation occurs:

```
segment .bss
    num1 resb 2
    num2 resb 2
    result resb 2

segment .text
    global _start

_start:
    ; adding 2 numbers inputted by the user
    mov eax, [num1]
    mov ebx, [num2]
    add eax, ebx
    mov [result], eax
    int 0x80

    ; output 
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, result
    mov edx, 2
```

lets say num1 = 2 and num2 = 2 then output should be "4" but output came out as "d"

Comment: You're on the right track. Also, note that "2" is not the same as 2. Users usually enter characters, not "numbers."

Comment: As @TomBlodget mentioned, you're mixing characters with the numbers they represent. Subtract `'0'` from each input, add them, then add `'0'` to the result before outputting.

Comment: where i say 2 that is where the user inputs 2 i have just assigned 2 bytes to it in the bss segment, also thanks for your replies i will try it out

Comment: @Michael this works well for when i set the length of the result to 1, but lets say i output a single number and the length is 2 a strange box with 4 1's and 0's output next to the actual value, and if the length is 1 and i output a double digit number a random symbol appears, how would i allow the length to be set dynamically based on what the result would be, thanks.

Comment: the OS services you have in linux will input/output to terminal characters, not numbers. So outputting "124" does involve outputting three bytes with values 49, 50 and 52 (those are the values in ASCII encoding assigned to characters '1', '2' and '4'). So if you have integer value 124 somewhere, you have to decompose it into separate 0..9 values for each power of 10, and then convert those into ASCII characters and output them in correct order and with desired alignment.. when working on "dynamic length", you still have to consider all limits involved (integer type, buffers for characters,...)

Comment: input is similar, you receive separate characters, and you may want to compose native integer value from them, i.e. what `atoi/scanf` functions do in C. Although it's also possible to write adder operating on ASCII strings, the native `add` instruction doing whole addition in single go over native types is not the only way how one can add values in assembly, for example databases often have "decimal" data types for floating point values defined in base-10, which are not native to CPU, so any operation with those is achieved by multiple CPU instructions, operating per-digit, etc..